# please help to make it work of vimscript

Tags: vim

why I can't set path success.

```
let s:WORKDIR = getcwd()
set path += ".," . s:WORKDIR . "/**"

echo &path
```

and the echo result is, my current directory is `"/home/myname/example"`, my expected result is
`".,/home/myname/example/**"`, but what i get is,

```
.,/usr/include,,
```

it seems this didn't work in my .vimrc script; please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax of the `:set` command is wrong; you should be getting errors, too. The `+=` must not be surrounded by whitespace, and you cannot use an expression on the right-hand side. Better use the `:let` command; it can also modify Vim options (`&optionname`), not just variables:

```
let &path .= ",.," . s:WORKDIR . "/**"
```